# Play2 Framework Float Format in Template

Tags: java, scala, templates, playframework-2.0, web-frameworks

I got a little Problem with a Float Value in a Play Template. I wrote this code

```
@String.format("%.2f",session.get("product."+product.id.toString).toFloat*product.vkBrutto)
```

and I got this error: 
Overloaded method value [format] cannot be applied to (String, Float)

I alredy tried other ways, but it wasn't successfull.
I'm searching for a possibility to get an output like this: 2,30
Maybe someone can help me,
thx

Comment: What type of error you get, compile or runtime error.
One advice try to simplify the value of the format, put it in a template method if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not the correct usage for `String.format`. `format` must be called on the instance of a `String`, which contains the formatting.

Example:

```
"%.2f".format(2.19387474)
```

returns "2.19".

You'll want something like this:

```
@{"%.2f".format(session.get("product."+product.id.toString).toFloat*product.vkBrutto)}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I just wonder that this works: @String.format("%.2f",product.vkBrutto)

Comment: Depends on what type `product.vkBrutto` is. Using the method in my response will be safer in Scala, as `String.format(format, object)` is a Java implementation. So when you pass it a `Float`, it doesn't work because `Float` isn't a Java `Object`.